# htaccess already stripping ".php" but need a sub page with url query

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's what I have so far...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?%1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

So site.com/page works to view site.com/page.php.

What I want to add to this is on one particular page where there is a query string...
example: site.com/song.php?name=Song-Name -> I want it to be site.com/song/Song-Name.

I know there are a lot of post similar to this and I've looked through a ton but just don't understand quite how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a new rule to handle `/song/` URIs:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^song/(.+)$ song.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

I have also corrected your 2nd rule since query string is already appended to target.